# marker disappears after setPosition on google maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I worked on a GPS position show on google maps. The issue here is that the google mark only appears on the first time (set the google marker part). It will disappeard every time after the setPosition method is called. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var index=0;
    var latitudes = new Array(35.71434,35.715612,35.711779,35.70913,35.710646);
    var longitudes = new Array(-77.92854,-77.924076,-77.925171,-77.925943,-77.930278);
    var mapOptions;
    var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes[index],longitudes[index]);
    var marker = null;
    var map;
    var newPoint;

    function autoUpdate(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
            mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: coords,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                    style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
                },
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
            );
            if(marker){
                newPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitudes[index],longitudes[index]);
                marker.setPosition(newPoint);
            }   
            else{
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: coords,
                    map: map,
                });
            }
            if(newPoint!=null){
                map.setCenter(newPoint);
                marker.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        index=index+1;
        if(index==5){
            index=0;
        }
        setTimeout(autoUpdate,5000);
    }

    autoUpdate();
</script>
<style type="text/css">
#mapContainer {
    height: 500px;
    width: 800px;
    border:10px solid #eaeaea;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapContainer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code that creates the map out of the autoUpdate function, only run it once on page load:

```
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: coords,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
            },
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("mapContainer"), mapOptions
        );
```

Or do something similar to what you do with the marker, only create it once, if it already has been initialized/created, just change the center.

Comment: Use a debugger so you can report _why_ it did not show the map (or at least use the javascript console check for errors).

Comment: Got it by using an if statement to check the map. Thanks a lot!