# Marker on google map are not shown after map loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use jquery.ui.map to load markers on google map, and this is part of my code:

```
            var ip = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, longt);


            var mapOptions = {
                zoom:     4,
                center:    ip,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            $('#map_canvas').gmap(mapOptions);


            var marker = $('#map_canvas').gmap('addMarker', {
                'position': ip, 
                'bounds': true,
                'title':'Your location'
            });
```

While the map is loading I can see the markers, but when everything are loaded the markers disappear and no marker is shown on the map, while we have them, if you take a look at this screen shot you will see that we have the marker (because we can see the marker title when we hover on it) but we cannot see it...

Screen shot: http://s15.postimg.org/5zlsbxwhn/scmap.jpg

The Demo page: http://bev.dev.beardo.co/encontre/

Comment: Possible dup and/or solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636908/marker-disappears-after-setposition-on-google-maps

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `marker.setMap(map)`

I have a nice example on [github](https://github.com/raam86/contact-page-with-map-for-wordpress/blob/master/assets/js/drawMap.js)